# className syntax in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am currently learning React and Redux. I have forked a boilerplate, and currently I am looking through all of the code to see how it fits together.

While scanning through some React Component files I found something very interesting! When setting `className` for many of the elements the syntax they use differs. The first time they use the following syntax:

```
<span className={classes['counter--green']}>
    ...
</span>
```

Then this syntax:

```
<button className='btn btn-default'>
    ...
</button>
```

And from there on out they use the following:

```
<h2 className={classes.counterContainer}>
    ...
</h2>
```

At the top of the file they import `classes` with the following:

```
import classes from './Counter.scss'
```

So simply my question is, **why are there three different syntax for className, and which one is correct**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the simple case:

```
<button className='btn btn-default'>
```

This just sets the class name to `"btn btn-default"`. You need to set `className` instead of `class` since you are writing JSX and that’s equivalent to setting the [`className` DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className), so you have to use `className` here.

```
<span className={classes['counter--green']}>
<h2 className={classes.counterContainer}>
```

These are both very similar. In JSX, to specify a more complex JavaScript expression, you need to put it inside curly braces. This would be equivalent to setting the `className` property like this:

```
someSpan.className = classes['counter--green'];
someH2.className = classes.counterContainer;
```

Finally, `classes` as imported using the `import classes from './Counter.scss'` syntax is a feature called [“CSS modules”](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). It involves a precompiler step that properly sets the class names later and makes sure that the style definitions are rendered to the HTML.

So to answer your final question, all of these are correct. What you want to use depends on where you want to define your styles (or where they are defined). Using CSS modules makes a lot of sense if you are creating independent components that might even get reused elsewhere. Using global CSS is good when you have an existing style sheet which you just want to use (e.g. here, these class names are likely from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)). And of course, you can also mix these, if you have global styles and want to add additional styles to it.

Comment: So I guess it really depends which one I use! Thank You

Answer (score 2):

In this case, without seeing the code, i'm guessing the boilerplate is using modular css (scss).

modular css can be imported,in this case as *classes*. Using modular css gives you css with local scope

all css rules imported from a module as classes are prefixed with the name classes.

and are to be treated as you treat object attributes

so css rule *counterContainer* is used as

```
classes.counterContainer
```

css rule name *counter-green* cannot use dot notation(because of the hyphen), so must use square bracket and string name notation as for any javascript object attribute

```
 classes['counter-green']
```

the third example *btn btn-default* is not imported from a css classes module but is instead imported globally. This is possibly a bootstrap class imported at root level as a link attribute on the index.html

Comment: Wow, interesting! Thank you, just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really unique to className, but for any JSX you can use curly braces `{}`'s to switch from "JSX mode" back to javascript to use any JS expression. Therefore in the first example they are setting the attribute `className` by  referencing an object called `classes` by the property `counter--green`, in the second example they are using a simple JSX string literal `'btn btn-default'`, and in the third example they are referencing the `classes` object by the property `counterContainer`. You can see the definition of the classes object according to the import at the end of your question.

They are all correct, they are simply different ways of doing it. By using JS expressions they are arguably more modular, by using a string literal it is easier to see in front of you what is going on, but less re-usable.